# Will Delphi compiler always fail when compiling a module with conditional-based type mismatch?

Tags: delphi, freepascal, conditional-compilation

For practical example, suppose `ModuleA` have some type varying on conditional compilation:

```
unit ModuleA;

interface

type
  { explicit character width }
  PASTR = type PAnsiChar;
  PWSTR = type PWideChar;
  { imlicit character width }
  PTSTR = {$IFDEF UNICODE}PWSTR{$ELSE}PASTR{$ENDIF};

  { ... }
```

And now the set of functions in `ModuleB` is depending on the type declared in `ModuleA`:

```
unit ModuleB;

{ ... }    

implementation

uses ModuleA;

{ explicit }
function FuncA(Arg: PASTR): Integer;
begin
  { do something with 1 byte char }
end;

function FuncW(Arg: PWSTR): Integer;
begin
  { do something with 2 byte char }
end;

{ implicit - will compiler safeguard against mismatching UNICODE define? }
function Func(Arg: PTSTR): Integer;
begin
  { map to explicit one }
  Result := {$IFDEF UNICODE}FuncW(Arg){$ELSE}FuncA(Arg){$ENDIF};
end;
```

Now, suppose `ModuleA` has been compiled with `UNICODE` symbol defined and DCU file has been generated. And then `ModuleB` has been compiled using DCU information only without `UNICODE` symbol (or vice versa case - `ModuleA.dcu` generated as ANSI, and then there is an attempt to use it in Unicode `ModuleB`).

Will Delphi compiler **always** fail when compiling a module with such conditional-based type mismatch? With `type` keyword and without it? Is there any version specific behaviour?

As a bonus: I'm interested in the same for Free Pascal.

Comment: As I remember compiler directives and symbols are local for unit and take no effect to other units. So you have to define (or not) `UNICODE` symbol in both modules. Usually this is done using include file with all common definitions. And it is same for FPC.

Comment: @Abelisto, I mean those module to be compiled separately, and mess to be created by erroneous compiling ANSI target against Unicode dependency (or vice versa, Unicode target against ANSI dependency).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler will fail to compile the program in that scenario. Both in Delphi and FPC.

One way to think about it is to expand the conditional code. Once written that way it becomes much clearer what the compiler will do. And this is the right mental model because that is how the compiler processes conditional code. It simply does not see the code that is in conditional branches that are not active.

Consider these two units:

```
unit Unit1;
// expanded with UNICODE defined

interface

type
  PASTR = type PAnsiChar;
  PWSTR = type PWideChar;
  PTSTR = PWSTR;

implementation

end.
```

---

```
unit Unit2;
// expanded with UNICODE undefined

interface

implementation

uses
  Unit1;

function FuncA(Arg: PASTR): Integer;
begin
end;

function FuncW(Arg: PWSTR): Integer;
begin
end;

function Func(Arg: PTSTR): Integer;
begin
  Result := FuncA(Arg);
end;

end.
```

The definition of `PTSTR` is found in `Unit1` and it is an alias to `PWSTR`. Hence the call to `FuncA` will not compile.

The use of `type` to make distinct types changes nothing either, because `PAnsiChar` and `PWideChar` are already incompatible.

Comment: <paranoia>Hm, so mess is possible when types are compatible, right?</paranoia>

Comment: I think that's right. You certainly don't need to define these new P*STR types. But if you had maybe AnsiString and UnicodeString switching then wackiness could ensue.

Comment: One way to reduce your concerns would be to switch on a true constant rather than a define. `const IsUnicode = {$IFDEF...}True{$ELSE}False{$ENDIF}`. Then use `{$IF IsUnicode}` everywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no, you could break it if you introduced a DEF or UNDEF of the UNICODE symbol, effectively overriding the directive you pass in when compiling.

Not sure why you would do something that daft, though.

Can't think of any version based difference, not breaking would be a catastrophic bug.